# Adding Sheet Names to Array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet

I am trying to add sheet names into an array in Excel VBA using the code below. It is only picking up one value (always the last worksheet name). For example, if I have 2 sheets: List1 and List2, it only picks up List2 and shows a blank value for the first sheet. If I add 4, it only shows the 4th, and so on. I'm not sure why I'm getting blank values.

```
Dim curSheet As Worksheet
Dim ArraySheets() As String
Dim x As Variant

For Each curSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If curSheet.Name Like "*List*" Then

        ReDim ArraySheets(x)

        ArraySheets(x) = curSheet.Name

        x = x + 1

    End If

Next curSheet
```

Comment: Replace `ReDim ArraySheets(x)` with `ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change `ReDim ArraySheets(x)` to `ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)`

When you use just `ReDim` the contents of the array are not kept, which is why you only get the final sheet name.  Using `ReDim Preserve` re-sizes the array while keeping the contents.

Comment: Is there a way to put the array definition (ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)) outside of the For loop? When I place it outside of the loop, I get a "Subscript out of range" error.

Answer (score 2):

Without loops

```
Sub GetNAmes()
Dim strIn As String
Dim X

strIn = Application.InputBox("Search string", "Enter string to find", "*List*", , , , , 2)
If strIn = "False" Then Exit Sub

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "shtNames", "=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND(""]"",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))"
X = Filter([index(shtNames,)], strIn, True, 1)

Select Case UBound(X)
    Case Is > 0
        strIn = Application.InputBox(Join(X, Chr(10)), "Multiple matches found - type position to select", , , , , 1)
        If strIn = "False" Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets(CStr(X(strIn))).Activate
        On Error GoTo 0
    Case 0
        Sheets(X(0)).Activate
    Case Else
        MsgBox "No match"
End Select

End Sub
```