# Finding Part of a Sheet Name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update a worksheet. The name of the worksheet changes with the date.

As an example the worksheet would have been named

> "Hello World 6.13" on Monday
> "Hello World 6.17" today

How can I looks for the sheet name that *starts* with "Hello World" and *ignores the date code*?

Comment: Have you researched the built in Left() function?

Comment: Also `Instr(...)` might be of some use.

Comment: worksheets(x).name like "Hello World*"

Comment: Provided that the workbook has been saved, this can be done with in-cell formulae: http://superuser.com/a/541771/576842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way I would go about this would be to loop through the sheets in the active workbook and make the comparison, and when the correct sheet "Hello World x.xx" is found set it as a reference, and use this reference to run any further code.

```
Let searchTerm = "Hello World"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left(ws.Name, Len(searchTerm)) = searchTerm Then
        Set hwSheet = ws
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws

'do some code eg:
With hwSheet
    .Range("A1").Value = "Hi"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was easy.  Didn't even think to use left >.<

Comment: @Addohm Glad to help, I think that sometimes complicated discussions around requirements that don't make sense can make us feel like we need a complicated solution, but fortunately we have SO to get some outsider input :)

Comment: Note that `Hello World` is `11` characters, both numbers need to match!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Good point - I've updated the code to account for other lengths of a `searchTerm`

Answer (score 0):

So the spreadsheet you want to capture is always the same sheet, in the same workbook?  If I've got this right, you can use the codename of the worksheet in the client's workbook, such as `Sheet1` instead of the worksheet name.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws as Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("Client.xls")
wb.Activate
Set ws = Sheet1
```

You would have to activate the appropriate workbook before using the sheet codename.  To be sure this works, it would be prudent to change the client's sheet codename to something unique (if it isn't already) if that is within your purview.

Comment: It's a good idea to use a sheet's Code(Name), but afaik you need not activating the *appropriate workbook*, because `Sheet1` refers to the current project you are executing your code and there's only one unique worksheet with this CodeName. It might be redundant as well to `Set ws = Sheet1` instead of referring to it directly, e.g. by including further code within a `With Sheet1` ... `End With` structure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Posted below is a version of Oliver's code that addresses working with the found sheet inside the loop, rather than the last found match.

A couple of other minor tweaks

- The string version of `Left$` is quicker than the variant `Left`
- if you set an object in a loop, should set it back to nothing before retesting (which is not evident in the code below as I used the existing `ws`)

*code*

```
Sub Updated()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left$(ws.Name, 11) = "Hello World" Then
        With ws
    'do something
        End With
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Another option to return all partial sheet matches without a loop is in [Adding Sheet Names to Array in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087836/adding-sheet-names-to-array-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

While I liked @Carrosives answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882970/5079799). I decided to functionalize it. In that regard, I didn't want to use `LEFT` or `RIGHT` but `InSTR`.

Here is what I got:

```
Public Function FindWorksheet(PartOfWSName As String) As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 If InStr(ws.Name, PartOfWSName) > 0 Then
  Debug.Print ws.Name
  Set FindWorksheet = ws
  Exit For
 End If
Next ws

End Function

Sub TestingSpot_Sub()

Dim PartOfWSName As String
PartOfWSName = "Testz"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = FindWorksheet(PartOfWSName)
ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough:

```
Sub CallTheRealThing()
Call SelectSheets("Sheet")
End Sub
Sub SelectSheets(NameNeededinSheet As String, Optional Looked_Workbook As Workbook)
Dim WorkSheetProject As Worksheet
    If Looked_Workbook Is Nothing Then Set Looked_Workbook = ThisWorkbook
    For Each WorkSheetProject In Looked_Workbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(WorkSheetProject.Name, NameNeededinSheet) Then: WorkSheetProject.Select: Exit Sub
    Next WorkSheetProject
End Sub
```

You may change it to a Function instead of sub to know if it could select the sheet or not