# Excel VBA - Creating array of worksheet names

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to create an array that contains all of the worksheet names, starting with the 4th worksheet in the active workbook.  I'm getting an error on 4th line when I try to redimension the array.  What am I missing?  There are currently 6 worksheets, the 3rd is hidden (in case that changes anything).

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetsToSkip() As Variant
For i = 4 To Sheets.Count
    ReDim Preserve sheetsToSkip(UBound(sheetsToSkip) + 1)
    sheetsToSkip(UBound(sheetsToSkip)) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
```

Comment: `sheetsToSkip` doesn't have a `Ubound` on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Why not just create an array or collection of worksheets btw?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30087836/3961708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigBen is on the right track. You only have to ReDim once:

```vb
Public Function ListWorkssheets()

    Dim SheetsToSkip()  As String
    Dim Count           As Integer
    Dim Index           As Integer
    
    Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ReDim SheetsToSkip(1 To Count)
    
    For Index = 1 To Count
        SheetsToSkip(Index) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets((Index + 3 - 1) Mod Count + 1).Name
    Next
    
    ' Verify.
    For Index = LBound(SheetsToSkip) To UBound(SheetsToSkip)
        Debug.Print Index, SheetsToSkip(Index)
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick couple of examples, if you make a count of the 'valid' sheets first ( if you're avoiding including sheets by name ) - that'll help.

-- Version 1 - don't bother checking (just get all sheet names to an array )

```
Sub SheetNamesToArray()

Dim MyWb As Workbook
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim SheetNameArray() As String  ' Array of Sheet Names
Dim LP As Integer ' ( Generic Loop Variable )

Set MyWb = ActiveWorkbook

    ':: Redim to workbook count
    ReDim SheetNameArray(MyWb.Sheets.Count)
    
    ':: Check Array Size
    Debug.Print UBound(SheetNameArray) & " = " & MyWb.Sheets.Count

    ':: Set Array from Sheet Names
    For LP = 1 To MyWb.Sheets.Count
        SheetNameArray(LP) = Sheets(LP).Name
        Debug.Print SheetNameArray(LP) & " :" & Sheets(LP).Name
    Next LP


End Sub
```

-- Version 2 - Check names, save only valid
( using Inst to test if multiple sheets have a particualar string in name )

```
Sub SheetNamesToArray_And_Ignore_Names()

Dim MyWb As Workbook
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim SheetNameArray() As String  ' Array of Sheet Names
Dim LP, LPx As Integer ' ( Generic Loop Variable(s) )
Dim MyValidSheetsCount As Integer  ' Array Size for only 'valid' sheets


    ':: Apply to active workbook
    Set MyWb = ActiveWorkbook

    For LP = 1 To MyWb.Sheets.Count
        ':: Skip over names to ignore..
        If InStr(1, Sheets(LP).Name, "Four", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            '::Iterate count of 'valid' sheets ::
            MyValidSheetsCount = MyValidSheetsCount + 1
        End If
    
    Next LP

    ':: Redim to workbook count
    ReDim SheetNameArray(MyValidSheetsCount)
    
    LPx = 0
    
    ':: Set Array from Sheet Names
    For LP = 1 To MyWb.Sheets.Count

        ':: Same test again, this time add to array, and iterate index variable ( LPX )
        If InStr(1, Sheets(LP).Name, "Four", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            SheetNameArray(LPx) = Sheets(LP).Name
            '::Iterate array index ::
            LPx = LPx + 1
        End If

    Next LP

    Debug.Print "Found " & LPx & " valid sheets" & vbNewLine
    
    ':: Check only the 'valid' sheets are recorded
    For LP = 0 To LPx - 1
      Debug.Print "(" & Format(LP, "000#") & ")  : " & SheetNameArray(LP)
    Next LP

End Sub
```

With VBA there's probably more than a few paths to getting the same result.

For the original question, if you're just trying to skip past 4 and aren't concerned they might be out of order , do :

```
Sub ReallySimpleJustUseNumbers()

':: N.B.  Sheets are indexed starting at 1, arrays begin at 0 ..

Dim MyWb As Workbook
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim SheetNameArray() As String  ' Array of Sheet Names
Dim LP As Integer ' ( Generic Loop Variable )

Set MyWb = ActiveWorkbook

    ':: Are there greater than four sheets in this workbook ?
    If MyWb.Sheets.Count > 4 Then
        ':: Redim to workbook count
        ReDim SheetNameArray(MyWb.Sheets.Count - 4)
    Else
        ':: Polite Exit
        MsgBox "Too Few Sheets buddy"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For LP = 4 To MyWb.Sheets.Count
        SheetNameArray(LP - 4) = MyWb.Sheets(LP).Name
    Next LP
    
    ':: Output array
    For LP = 0 To UBound(SheetNameArray)
        Debug.Print LP & " --- " & SheetNameArray(LP)
    Next LP

End Sub
```

This'll simply start populating the array as defined as Count of Sheets  - Four initial sheets, index starting at  0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array `sheetsToSkip` does not have an upper bound in the first loop cycle yet. You can check if `sheetsToSkip` is an array in the first loop and then either dimension it for the first time or resize it.

Suggestion for the code:

```
Sub CreateSheetNameArray()
    Dim i As Integer
    'Brakets are removed
    Dim sheetsToSkip As Variant

    For i = 4 To Sheets.Count
        If IsEmpty(sheetsToSkip) Then
            ReDim sheetsToSkip(0 To 0)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve sheetsToSkip(UBound(sheetsToSkip) + 1)
        End If
        sheetsToSkip(UBound(sheetsToSkip)) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Be aware that `ReDim Preserve` is slow. If you have a lot of loop cycles, you might consider to just dimension the array before the loop.